# Why are duplicate messages being logged

Tags: c++, logging, log4cplus

I'm new to log4cplus. I have the following configuration:

```
log4cplus.rootLogger=TRACE, STDOUT 

log4cplus.logger.zios.utl.Thread=DEBUG, STDOUT

log4cplus.appender.STDOUT=log4cplus::ConsoleAppender
log4cplus.appender.STDOUT.layout=log4cplus::PatternLayout
log4cplus.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{%H:%M:%S} [%t] - %m%n
```

which I load with the following code:

```
try {
    log4cplus::PropertyConfigurator::doConfigure("log4cplus.properties");
} catch (...) {
    cout << "exception occured while opening log4cplus.properties" << endl;
}
```

It loads without incident but whenever I log something, I get two messages appearing in my log.  For example, I log using this code:

```
Logger log = Logger::getInstance("zios.utl.Thread");
LOG4CPLUS_DEBUG(log, "Thread created");
```

and what appears in the log is:

```
17:10:48 [3075459952] - Thread created
17:10:48 [3075459952] - Thread created
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 3):

You have one appender and you use it twice, for two loggers:

```
log4cplus.rootLogger=TRACE, STDOUT 
log4cplus.logger.zios.utl.Thread=DEBUG, STDOUT
```

This means that the appender is attached to root logger and `zios.utl.Thread` logger.